# Proving this theorem about the skinny baker map

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I'm working on a project for a class on Dynamical systems, and I've come to a point where even the professor was unable to help me. He excused me from having to prove it directly, but out of my own curiosity, and because I think it will help the later steps, I've come here to see if anyone can prove it.

We are using the skinny baker map, defined as:
\begin{equation}
  B(x,y) =
    \begin{cases}
      (\frac{1}{3}x, 2y) & \text{if 0 $\leq y \leq \frac{1}{2}$}\\
      (\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{2}{3}, 2y-1) & \text{if $\frac{1}{2} < y \leq 1$}\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Now, this is the theorem it is asking us to prove:

$Theorem$: Let **B** denote the skinn baker map, and let $d>0$. Assume there is a set of points $\{{x_0, x_1, ..., x_{k-1}, x_k=x_0}\}$ such that each coordinate of **B**$(x_i)$ and $x_i$ differs by less than $d$ for $i=0,1,...,k-1$. Then there is a periodic orbit $\{z_0,z_1,...,z_{k-1}\}$ such that $|x_i-z_i|<2d$ for $i=0,1,...,k-1$.

So far, to solve this, I have shown that **B**$(S_i)$ lies across $S_{i+1}$, where $S_i$ is the $3d$ by $2d$ rectangle centered at $x_i$. This allows me to conclude by a corollary that **B**$^k$ has a fixed point in $S_0$. That was provided in the hint.

From here, I really just don't know how to show that the periodic orbit exists with the given inequality $|x_i-z_i|<2d$ for $i=0,1,...,k-1$. I'm really just struggling with the inequality part.

Thank you for any help, and I probably won't be able to figure this out on my own.